# Is This a Virus?

Tags: malware, virus, software, spyware, trojan

I want to ask about a program is it malware or a program from Mozilla?

When I turn on my pc it starts normally but I see an open program called **update.exe** and it has a firefox icon on it, when I click on the icon in the taskbar to see what the program does, it closes.  And all open programs also begin to shut down automatically, until I kill the program from the task manager.

I found the path of the program and opened it but I didn't click on it in the taskbar, so the program remained open I opened the Process Hacker tool to see what was happening, the program is connected with different domains some of which are from amazon servers and some IPs were in united states.

I 'am not sure what's that, I scanned the program with malwarebytes and avast but didn't find any malware, I searched on google but can't find any pieces of information about that.

If someone can give me any information I am curious about that. The path of program: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Neptune`

Comment: Upload the executable to VirusTotal.com. The results may be more informative than a single scanner.

Comment: even virusTotal says that the program is clean but some comments there says that is a goodware
https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/fb9045b74615a339fcdc3016f899aec5b8afbdacde5421d94d777c709295c2fd/detection

Comment: You may want to reinstall firefox. See if that stops the issues.

Comment: i uninstalled firefox ,and deleted the program ,the issues stopped so i guess it's malware right ?

Comment: I would guess it's NOT malware. None of the scans were positive, and uninstalling the program stopped it. If it was malware it wouldn't let itself be uninstalled.

Comment: i didn't uninstall the program ,i removed the folder containing it(Neptune).
the program is some how linked with firefox ,i uninstalled firefox  so i can delete the program, cause it does not wants to deleted when firefox is installed

Comment: Maybe it was a browser plugin.  Did you install any new antivirus recently?  They sometimes add extensions to the browser.

Comment: Hmm i guess Spybot

Answer (score 1):

A bit late.

1. If it was from Mozilla or anything to do with Firefox, it would not be using the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Neptune`.
2. The fact that it is showing a Firefox Icon means it is trying to mislead you.
3. And the fact that it installed itself without your knowledge means that it's not above board.

These are classified as **Malware**. They download themselves over the browser and have unwanted effects. Virus scanners will often not find them, but Malwarebytes and Zemana do find them.

The reason they are not classified as viruses is that they don't normally do any damage.  I have had one that would insert ads in the middle of the web pages in the browser.  Another one would add multiple download buttons to the web pages.

The only thing I have found named **Neptune** is that it was the code name for a version of Windows being worked on, in 1999.  So my advice to anyone in the future is to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem
It is not a malware. It got classified as a PUP by malwarebytes. PUP: potentially unwanted program. It got on my device due to installing google chrome browser (.exe) from an unknown source. This is why you should always install software from it’s reliable source and don’t use third party app stores.

Malwarebytes logs

PUP.Optional.FirefoxSNR.Generic.

I hope this helps those who face same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the community. How does this answer exactly relate to the question when the browser in the question is Firefox?...